# hangover spoj, what is wrong in the solution?

Tags: c++

Input

The input consists of one or more test cases, followed by a line containing the number 0.00 that signals the end of the input. Each test case is a single line containing a positive floating-point number c whose value is at least 0.01 and at most 5.20; c will contain exactly three digits.

Output

For each test case, output the minimum number of cards necessary to achieve an overhang of at least c card lengths. Use the exact output format shown in the examples.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
float num;
    cin>>num;
    round(num);
    cout<<"0.00"<<endl;
    float temp = 0.00;
    float n=2.00;
    int count1=0;

    while(temp<num)
    {
        temp+=1.0/(n);
        n++;
        count1++;
    }
    cout<<count1<<" card(s)"<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try your code with the supplied test cases?  Did it work?  You might include at least a link to the problem so people don't need to search for it.  Keep in mind a question is generally something somewhat specific, not just "Why doesn't this work?"  You need to do some work to narrow down the problem and show the input, expected output, and incorrect output.

Comment: I believe that "c will contain exactly three digits" is a hint that floating point arithmetic isn't your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

> The input consists of **one or more** test cases...

Your code doesn't work with '*more*'.